# How do I parse XML with Java?

Tags: java, xml

I have a huge XML file without an XML schema, and I would like to parse and extract some information from it.
How do I parse XML with Java?

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Comment: Your question is very vague. I suggest you to provide more details about what you want to parse and the efforts which you have made to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in 2 ways using 
Using DOM Parser
Using SAX Parser
Using StAX Parser

for code please refer the following tutorials

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html

Comment: If the file is huge, as stated in the question, I'm not convinced it is a good idea to perform DOM parsing.